# The error message "Unable to load popup -please try again" when I start a bounty

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, bounty

Recently, I tried to start a bounty for two of my questions. But the error message "Unable to load popup -please try again" appears every time I start the bounty.

[image]

I don't know whether it is a error or a restriction on my action.

Please have a check on it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a pop-up blocker installed in your browser?

Comment: @hardmath, I have carefully checked that no such program is turned on. I even meet this error message when using my smartphone.

Comment: And now there is also a post on Meta Stack Exchange: [Eeeek! Can't start a bounty on any question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320687).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copying my answer from [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320693/164200):

> Thanks for reporting this. It has been fixed across the network now and you should be able to add bounties until your heart is content.
>
> Thanks to [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha) who smashed the bug very quickly.